# Fees for commercial Apps published into Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

while reading through the online documentation I do not understand if:

- there are some fees for commercial Apps published into GAM (or CWS) or the one time 5$ would suffice;
- it is mandatory to have a Google Wallet account or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you publish your first item, you must pay a one-time US$5.00 developer registration fee. They charge this fee in order to verify developer accounts and better protect users against fraudulent activity.

The 5$ fee is just to verify the developer account.

Check this [page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/about_signup) for more details.

I believe all the payments to Google goes through Google wallet only. However, you have to provide your card information in Google wallet while you are paying.

Hope that helps!